# Response.Appendheader is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, download

Here is the code I use to download(save) a file from webserver to client machine using google chrome browser.The file on server is pdf file.I tried using both Response.AppendHeader & Response.Appendheader. It doesn't throw me up any errors and also doesn't show me any dialog box or doesn't download file.Any help appreciated.

```
        string pdfPathGLSummary = @"c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\sueTesting\\App_Data\\\GlSummary.pdf";
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Clear();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=GlSummary.pdf");
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(@"c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\sueTesting\\App_Data\\\GlSummary.pdf");
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Comment: have you tried it without the TransmitFile line also try changing the AddHeader to `context.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}.pdf", fileName));` filename in yourcase would be `GlSummary` I would create a variable to hold and or pass in the file name also if you are going to use TransmitFile use something like this `Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/SavedFolder/" + filename));` perhaps the path on the server is not what you think it is..

Comment: Perhaps something to do with the path you have specified? If you are prefixing your string constants with `@` then you don't need to escape the backslashes. So your string has way too many!

Comment: I think the content type should be all lowercase as well, i.e. "application/pdf" and not "Application/pdf".

Answer (score 2):

The string you have specified for the filename is prefixed with `@` meaning that it is a [verbatim string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) and hence the multiple backslashes are being included.

```
@"c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\sueTesting\\App_Data\\\GlSummary.pdf"
```

Should be changed to one of these:

```
@"c:\inetpub\wwwroot\sueTesting\App_Data\GlSummary.pdf"
"c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\sueTesting\\App_Data\\GlSummary.pdf"
```

Note the triple backslash you have in your code.